# customize function of aggregating time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

say I have the following time series data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.date_range('2015-07-01', periods=20, freq='D')
y = [0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x, columns=['value'])
df
```

[image]

Then a resampling is done on weekly basis, and aggregation is now counting both zero and non-zero elements:

```
weekly = df.resample('W').agg({
    'nonzero': np.count_nonzero, 
    'zero': lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x==0)})
weekly
```

[image]

What I actually want to do is take the *result* of aggregation, and do something about it (e.g., apply a function), say `2 * number of non-zero + 3 * number of zeros`, how do I go about it? Do I have to do that on a separate step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what need.

If need only output of combined both functions:

```
weekly = df.resample('W').agg({
    'custom': lambda x: 3 * np.count_nonzero(x==0) + 2 * np.count_nonzero(x)})
print (weekly)
           custom
            value
2015-07-05     12
2015-07-12     14
2015-07-19     18
2015-07-26      2
```

If need `zero`, `nonzero` columns too is possible repeating functions:

```
weekly = df.resample('W').agg({
    'nonzero': np.count_nonzero, 
    'zero': lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x==0),
    'custom': lambda x: 3 * np.count_nonzero(x==0) + 2 * np.count_nonzero(x)})
print (weekly)
           nonzero  zero custom
             value value  value
2015-07-05       3     2     12
2015-07-12       7     0     14
2015-07-19       3     4     18
2015-07-26       1     0      2
```

But for better performance is use only arithemtic operations after `resample` + `sum`:

```
weekly[('custom1', 'value')] = 2 * weekly[('nonzero', 'value')] + 3 * weekly[('zero', 'value')]
print (weekly)
           nonzero  zero custom custom1
             value value  value   value
2015-07-05       3     2     12      12
2015-07-12       7     0     14      14
2015-07-19       3     4     18      18
2015-07-26       1     0      2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
weekly['custom'] = 2 * weekly['nonzero'] + 3 * weekly['zero']
print(weekly)
```

**Output**

```
            zero nonzero custom
           value   value       
2015-07-05     2       3     12
2015-07-12     0       7     14
2015-07-19     4       3     18
2015-07-26     0       1      2
```